# Refresh the RecyclerView view in android

Tags: android

I have customer and merchant if i add any item in customer that new item add to merchant list in merchant screen move on back to come merchant screen  only it is show new item now i want get new item without go back to previous activity.I used RecyclerView list in my class. i used the below code. i didn't work for me.I get the merchat list via API

```
LinearLayoutManager myLinear=new LinearLayoutManager(OnGoingCases.this);
myLinear.setStackFromEnd(true);
myLinear.setReverseLayout(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLinear);
adapter = new OnGoingCasesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ongoing_case, listener);
```

I used this code to refresh the `RecyclerView`

```
 adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, ongoing_case.size());
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider)));
```

Comment: call your notify datasetchanged method after setadapter

Comment: Sorry i got same result

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask